# why can not read cookie setted by javascript with php on explorer?

Tags: php, javascript, internet-explorer, cookies, opera

I have one problem and I need help. I am doing some simple steps:

1. i set a cookie with php(if it is not already set).
2. I read this cookie again with php and it works fine (to all browsers!).
3. I reset the cookie that i set previously, with javascript this time.
4. I read the cookie setted by javascript with php and on firefox, chrome it works fine, but on explorer, opera, safari (i use the latest versions) it doesn't work. cookie can't be read. no error return but the field of the cookie are blank. plz see the code below.

**php code:**

```
<?php
    if (isset($_COOKIE["parameters"])){
            $UserParam = json_decode($_COOKIE["parameters"],true);
            print_r($UserParam); // when the cookie is set by php it prints the array (on all browsers), but when cookie is set by javascript nothing print on explorer,opera,safari.
            echo"<script>function readCookie(){ alert(\"the cookie was there with radius: ".$UserParam['radius']." type: ".$UserParam['type']."\"); //again when the cookie set with php the variables have values on every browser, but when the cookie set with javascript no values to the variables.
                            getLocationFunction(\"".$UserParam["radius"]."\",\"".$UserParam["type"]."\",\"".$UserParam["date"]."\",\"".$UserParam["name"]."\")}</script>";
    }
    else { 
            $defaultParam = array("radius" => "ως 50km","type" => "all","date" => "unlimited", "name" => "all");
            $defaultParamSerialized = json_encode($defaultParam);
            setcookie("parameters","$defaultParamSerialized",time()+3600);
            echo"<script>function readCookie(){ alert(\"there was no cookie so i set it: radius ".$defaultParam["radius"]."\");
                             getLocationFunction(\"".$defaultParam["radius"]."\",\"".$defaultParam["type"]."\",\"".$defaultParam["date"]."\",\"".$defaultParam["name"]."\")
                        }
                </script>";
    }

?>
```

**javascript code:**

```
function renewCookie(){ 
    var myArray = {radius: radius, type: type, date: price , name: company };
    var valueSerialized = JSON.stringify(myArray);
    createCookie('parameters',valueSerialized,999);   
  }
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
  }
```

Again, I read the cookie in all situation with php, but when I create it with php it can be read lovely to all browsers, when i create it with javascript it can be read fine to firefox, chrome but not on explorer, opera and safari.

note1: there is no syntax error.

note2: browsers are the latest versions.

plz help. thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you checked valueSerialized contains your array in these browsers. Maybe you need to qoute the keys of your array??

Comment: @BassJobsen if we are talking about the same think i have done this and i sow that javascript serialized the value of the cookie in different way than php do. but the same think also happen in firefox and in chrome but it works as i said. any farther instructions?

Comment: most function to write the cookie, like http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp use escape() on the value

Answer (score 1):

Try that,

Change this

```
if (isset($_COOKIE["parameters"])){
```

with this

```
$COOKIE = isset($_COOKIE["parameters"]) ? $_COOKIE["parameters"] : "";
```

And use `print_r($_COOKIE)` with any browsers to see the difference.

Comment: thank you for your answer but the problem is not the if statement but how javascript encode the data in the cookie. and i solve it with the suggestion of Bass Jobsen to use escape() like w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp.